Can you combine stacked and clustered columns in an excel chart?
I am analysing failure modes of a machine using pareto analysis, but I keep adding more data and struggling to represent it correctly on the chart.
In the image linked below, the three bars represent the number of failures (total failures, failures that passed second time, failures that passed after 3+ times). I would like to combine 2nd/3rd time passes into 1 stacked column. However when I change one column, all other columns change automatically. So I can only have 3 separate clustered bars (as below), or a single stacked bar. Is there a way to keep the bars separate?
I have seen that using a second axis can keep the bars separate. But then they will appear in the same place on the x axis and overlap, so it still appears stacked.Also I'm already using the second axis for the line, so I'd prefer to keep all bars on the same axis.


AFAIK it is impossible to achieve such an effect in a simple way. It can only be achieved by indirectly combining and overlaying data. The main and the secondary axes should be used.
From the data originally in Series 2 and 3 that you want to form a stacked column, create a new series by summing the corresponding values. This will be Series 2 on the new chart.
On the main axis of the new chart, we will place the original Series 1 and the new Series 2. We will create a new Series 3, made up of zeros, and a new Series 4, which will be a copy of the original Series 2. We will overlay these two series on the same chart using the secondary axis.
The data for the summary line (new Series 5) must be calculated to match the axis scale.


This is the best I could do, but it's not in bars. I'm not sure it's possible to put stacked bars next to a regular one.

